# How is $[Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt3 ) : Q(\sqrt2)]=2$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

$\mathbb{Q}$ is the rationals. I know that $\sqrt3 \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ but so what? The answer to this question seems to be based upon that. Really don't understand what that means in finding the minimal polynomial.

Comment: The set $\{1,\sqrt{3}\}$ is a basis for $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ over $Q(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: $x^2-3$ is irreducible in $Q(\sqrt{2})$, hence $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) = Q(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3}) \simeq Q(\sqrt{2})[x] / (x^2-3)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that $\sqrt{3}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, then you know the degree is greater than $1$. But $\sqrt{3}$ is a root of the equation $x^2-3=0$, which has coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, so the degree is exactly $2$.

Comment: How come you didn't write anything about irreducibility? Did you somehow know that it is at max 2 or something?

Comment: You essentially took care of the irreducibility by your assertion that $\sqrt{3}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.  I assume you have a proof. If we know the degree is $\gt 1$, and $\le 2$, it must be exactly $2$. No need to refer explicitly to the irreducibility of $x^2-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, though that is a consequence of degree $2$, and also a consequence of $\sqrt{3}$ not being in the field.

Comment: But how do we know the degree is at max 2 though????#

Comment: Because $ x^2 - 3 $ is the minimal polynomial of $ \sqrt{3} $ over $ \mathbb{Q} $, so its minimal polynomial over $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) $ has to divide that.

Comment: Because $\sqrt{3}$ is the root of a polynomial of degree $2$. Always, if $\alpha$ is a root of a polynomial of degree $k$ over the field $F$, then $F(\alpha)$ has degree $\le k$ over $F$. (The degree is exactly $k$ if the polynomial is irreducible.)

Comment: Note by the way that you did the only "hard" part of the work when you showed that $\sqrt{3}$ was not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. As you can see from the length of my answer, the rest is very easy.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\sqrt3\in Q(\sqrt2)$, then write $\sqrt3=a+b\sqrt2, a,b\in Q$, 
Remark that $a,b$ are not zero, if $a=0$, then $\sqrt2\sqrt3=b(\sqrt2)^2=2b=\sqrt6$, this is not true since $\sqrt6$ is not in $Q$. Suppose $b=0$, then $\sqrt3=a\in Q$ this is not true.

you obtain $3=(a+b\sqrt2)^2=a^2+2ab\sqrt2+2b^2$. This implies that $\sqrt2={{3-a^2-2b^2}\over{2ab}}\in Q$. This is not true, so $\sqrt3$ is not in $Q(\sqrt2)$.

Since the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt3\in Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ is $x^2-3$. You deduce that $[Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3):Q(\sqrt2)]\leq 2$ thus is $2$ since $\sqrt3$ is not an element of $Q(\sqrt2)$.